# XBee wifi module does not send HTTP Post Request

Tags: http, post, xbee

I have connected an XBee wifi module to my computer using an XB Explorer USB Dongle.

I have used XCTU to configure the Xbee to connect to an Access point (a samsung mobile phone) and verified that it is connected by checking the phone.

The problem is that I am unable to send HTTP POST request to my NodeJS web server however.

Here are my settings:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH4At.png)

I entered the server address in 'destination address' and 'BB8' (which is hex 3000) in the destination port. I've left source address as the default.

I'm trying to use the XCTU console to send an HTTP POST request. Here is the HTTP POST request. I send it as a packet without entering command mode:

```
POST /addreading HTTP/1.1
Host: 52.210.255.61:3000
User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 114

{"readings":[["2016","11","24","03","11","25","110","75","60"],["2016","11","26","06","18","56","135","78","62"]]}
```

The request is not received at the server. I've been stuck for a few hours with this and I'd appreciate any help. Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: Are you sure the server is receiving requests correctly?  I just tried it from my computer and it refused the connection.

Comment: @tomlogic Yeah, the server was running when I tried. I just didn't detach it from the terminal so it got terminated. I'll leave it running now.

Comment: Just wondering if you've isolated the problem to the XBee Wi-Fi.  Can you make connections to your server from other devices?  Does the connection attempt show up in the logs?  Can the XBee Wi-Fi connect to other web servers or do a simple GET?  Can you see the connection attempts if you use Wireshark or tcpdump to monitor the network?